# What is the chance of a Globally Unique Identifier consisting out of only digits?

Tags: probability

A Globally Unique Identifier (GUID) consists of 32 hexadecimal characters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). Is the chance of a GUID that consists of only digits as simple as 10/16 to the power of 32?

I have a feeling that this is a too simple approach and something like Benford's Law might skew with the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your answer is correct, assuming the GUIDs are generated by generating each digit independently of these others and uniformly over the digits (which is a reasonable assumption).

Benford's law occurs in situations where the numbers under consideration signify quantities, where larger quantities are less likely. Since the numbers (of a certain fixed length) starting with 1 signify relatively smaller quantities, they are more common, giving rise to the law.

Comment: +1 yes, I think OP's answer is correct: $$\left(\frac{10}{16}\right)^{32}$$